# Can we migrate document inside a collection from one cluster shard to another cluster shard

Tags: mongodb

Example:

[image]

A user is in zone NA and he wants to move to region EU permanently.

Lets say if I want to move user (1 Document) from user collection in Shard 1 in NA to Shard N + 1 in EU.

I have seen shard migration but not one document inside a particular collection to another collection in other zone shard.

Answer (score 0):

With MongoDB 4.2 you can update shard key value which will move the document to desired region.

Here's the link for full explanation and an example on how to do it.

https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/core/sharding-change-shard-key-value/